# determine if javascript is already registered in head

Tags: javascript, .net, vb.net

I want to programatically add a script reference to the head of my page from a user control. I avoided using `ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` as this doesn't add the script to the head, but the body of the document.

I added my script like this:

```
 Dim Include As New HtmlGenericControl("script")
 Include.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript")
 Include.Attributes.Add("src", _ckEditorScript)
 Me.Page.Header.Controls.Add(Include)
```

What I'm unsure of is a way to check if this script is already registered so that I can avoid adding it multiple times if a control is registered more than once on a page.

At one point I added an id

```
Include.Attributes.Add("id", "ckEditorScript")
```

and tried locating it like this, but with no success.

```
If Me.Page.Header.FindControl("ckEditorScript") Is Nothing Then
```

I hope someone can help.

Comment: Depending on your project you could add your reference as simple HTML in your master-site.

Comment: True, but the ckeditor is a big script, and we already have lots of scripts registered. I dont really want to force people to download it if they dont have too

Comment: I see. Just one more question out of curiosity: Why bother if the JS is in `<head>` or `<body>`? I don't think that it matters much and you coudl've check the `Key` when using `RegisterClientScriptBlock` pretty easily.

Comment: You're right, I'm probably old fashioned in that I like my scripts in the head. Although Google seems to be advising to put them at the bottom these days, Ive always had them in the head.

Answer (score 0):

I was nearly there, Stupidly I was referencing the client id. I;ve converted to:

```
    If Me.Page.Header.FindControl("ckeditorScript") Is Nothing Then
        Dim Include As New HtmlGenericControl("script")
        Include.ID = "ckeditorScript"
        Include.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript")
        Include.Attributes.Add("src", _ckEditorScript)
        Me.Page.Header.Controls.Add(Include)
    End If
```

Slight niggle that it adds an id attribute to my script, so unfortunately netscape 4 users may have issues!